# bash script to create directories named after file names then move and rename files to corresponding directories

Tags: bash, file, directory

I looked all day from tutorials to ready made bash scripts, but couldn't find what I need. Also I never wrote a bash script before... :/

Here's my problem (to quote from full metal jacket: "there are many like it, but this one is mine"): I have a directory with 120 files that come in triplets (in bold I marked what's unique to every file triplet):

GSM6025**613**_SJWLM**030043**_D1_barcodes.tsv
GSM6025**613**_SJWLM**030043**_D1_features.tsv
GSM6025**613**_SJWLM**030043**_D1_matrix.mtx

GSM6025**615**_SJWLM**071563**_D1_barcodes.tsv
GSM6025**615**_SJWLM**071563**_D1_features.tsv
GSM6025**615**_SJWLM**071563**_D1_matrix.mtx

...

I would like to have a bash script that creates new directories with names according to the triplets unique strings (f.e. '613', '615') moves the three corresponding files (*barcode.tsv, *features.tsv, *matrix.mtx) to the corresponding directory and renames them so that the files are just called "barcode.tsv", "features.tsv" and "matrix.mtx".

I tried it with a for loop, but I'm pretty blank on bash scripting and beyond the second line, honestly, it's all jibberish to me (for now)... :/

```
`#!/bin/bash
for f in *.{tsv,mtx}
do
...
done`
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code (maybe on a copy of your directory first!):

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s nullglob

for file in GSM6025[0-9][0-9][0-9]_*_{features.tsv,matrix.mtx,barcodes.tsv}
do 
    dir=${file#GSM6025}
    dir=${dir%%_*}

    newfile=${file##*_}

    mkdir -p -v -- "$dir"
    mv -n -v -- "$file" "$dir/$newfile"
done
```

- `shopt -s nullglob` makes globs expand to nothing when nothing matches (otherwise they expand to the glob pattern itself, which is almost never useful in programs).
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for explanations of `${file#GSM6025}` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to split the file name into its components, something like this

```
file='GSM6025615_SJWLM071563_D1_barcodes.tsv'
eval $(sed -E 's/(GSM....)([0-9]+)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)\.tsv/n=\2;f=\5;/' <<< "$file")
echo $n
615
echo $f
barcodes
```

`eval` allows you to take the output of `sed` (the `n` and `f` variable assignments) and convert it to variables.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting one line `awk` script:

```
awk '{d=substr($1,8);printf("mkdir -p %s;mv %-38s %s\n",d,$0,d"/"$4);}' FS="_" <<< $(ls *.csv *.mtx)
```

If the output commands are satisfactory, run the output:

```
bash <<< $(awk '{d=substr($1,8);printf("mkdir -p %s;mv %-38s %s\n",d,$0,d"/"$4);}' FS="_" <<< $(ls *.csv *.mtx))
```

#### `awk` script explanation:

```
BEGIN{FS="_"} # set awk field seperator to "_"
{ # for each file name input
  dir=substr($1,8); # extract dir name from 1st field
  printf("mkdir -p %s;mv %-38s %s\n", # format output command with printf
    dir, # 1st argument dir value
    $0,  # 2nd argument unchanged input file name
    dir"/"$4); # 3rd argument dir appended with 4th field
}
```